# Problema con Struct dinamicos C

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un programa en C que consiste en crear puntos de 2 coordenadas (x, y) tanto de fora aleatoria como manualente. Luego almacenar unos datos de los mismos puntos en un struct. Despues almacenarlo en ***compendioDePuntos.txt***.

El struct:

```
struct puntos{
 int idPunto;
 float valorX;
 float valorY;
 float Modulo;
 float Angulo;
}
```

Para asignar puntos manualmente:

```
scanf("%d", &aux1);
punto=(struct puntos*)malloc(sizeof(aux1));
if(punto == NULL){
    printf("Error en Malloc()");
}
else{
    arch = fopen("compendioDePuntos.txt","w+");
    if(arch==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo crear el archivo");
    }
    else{
        for (i = 0; i < aux1; i++){
                Valv:
        //    textcolor(RED+BLINK);
        //    cprintf("****Coloca unicamente valores entre -200 a 200****\n");
                  punto[i].idPunto = i+1;
                  printf("Ingresa el Valor en x del punto numero %i \n", i+1);
                  scanf("%f",&punto[i].valorX);
                  printf("Ingresa el Valor en y del punto numero %i \n", i+1);
                  scanf("%f",&punto[i].valorY);

                if(punto[i].valorX>200 || punto[i].valorY>200 || punto[i].valorX<(-200) || punto[i].valorY<(-200) ){
            //cprintf("Error, porfavor solo pon valores de -200 a 200 unidades porfavor");
            goto Valv;
                }
            else{
                    punto[i].Modulo=modulo(punto[i].valorX,punto[i].valorY);
                    punto[i].Angulo=angulop(punto[i].valorX,punto[i].valorY);

                    fprintf(arch,"%d",punto[i].idPunto);
                    fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\t" ,punto[i].valorX);
                    fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\t" ,punto[i].valorY);
                    fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\t" ,punto[i].Modulo);
                    fprintf(arch,"\t%.3f\n" ,punto[i].Angulo);
            }
        system("cls");
        }
    fclose(arch);
    }
free(punto);
imprimir();
}
```

y para asignar valores al azar uso la funcion numeror:

```
float numeror(int num){
 float ranint,ransig;

    num = num+1;

    ranint=rand() % num;
    ransig=rand() % 2;

    if(ransig=0){
        ranint = -ranint;
    }
    else{
        ranint = ranint;
    }

 return ranint;
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al intentar introducir mas de 3 puntos manualmente el archivo txt queda en blanco, si lo hago de forma manual, pero si lo hago de forma aleatoria, el archivo parece que se corrompe puesto que enseña muchos simbolos ASCII al azar. Creo que es por un error de memoria porque mi compilador (gcc) marca un ***Aborted (core dumped)***, aunque la verdad no se si sea eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d", &aux1);
punto=(struct puntos*)malloc(sizeof(aux1));
```

No lo has puesto, pero supongo que *aux1* es un *int*.

*sizeof(aux1)* te dará entonces el tamaño de un int, y eso es el espacio que reservará el *malloc*.

Luego intentas escribir datos asumiento que tienes un array de *aux1* puntos, que necesitaría mucha más memoria.

A partir de aquí es comportamiento indefinido, no se sabe cuándo o cómo fallará el programa.

Supongo que lo que querías hacer era:

```
scanf("%d", &aux1);
punto=(struct puntos*)malloc(sizeof(struct puntos) * aux);
```

El resto del programa parece estar bien, pero tendrás que probarlo una vez hayas resuelto esto.

Comment: me aparece un error, puntos no ha sido declarado

Comment: ya lo resolvi, solo es poner sizeof(struct puntos) * aux1)